# How to fix 'Uploading service to Engine → Unknown directive "key"' error when trying to push a service to Apollo Engine?

Tags: typescript, apollo-server

When I try to push my apollo-server application to the Apollo Engine via `apollo service:push --endpoint=http://localhost:4001` I get an error:
`Uploading service to Engine → Unknown directive "key".` What am I doing wrong?

I'm currently setting up a backend project with a bunch of microservices and I want to use Apollos new managed federation feature where every microservice's graphql schema is pushed to the Apollo graph manager and combined by an apollo gateway server.

My schema looks like this:

```
extend type Query {
  me: User
}

type User @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  username: String
}
```

These are my resolvers:

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    me() {
      return users[0];
    }
  },
  User: {
    __resolveReference(object) {
      return users.find(user => user.id === object.id);
    }
  }
};
```

And this is my server setup:

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: buildFederatedSchema([{ typeDefs, resolvers }])
});

server.listen({ port: 4001 }).then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

apollo.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  service: {
    localSchemaFile: "./src/graphql/schema.graphql"
  }
};
```

Here is the full error message:

```
npx apollo service:push --endpoint=http://localhost:4001
  √ Loading Apollo Project
  × Uploading service to Engine
    → Unknown directive "key".
GraphQLSchemaValidationError: Unknown directive "key".
    at Object.buildSchemaFromSDL (C:/Users/Juliu/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_npx/13168/node_modules/apollo/node_modules/apollo-graphql/lib/schema/buildSchemaFromSDL.js:38:15)
    at FileSchemaProvider.resolveSchema (C:/Users/Juliu/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_npx/13168/node_modules/apollo/node_modules/apollo-language-server/lib/providers/schema/file.js:24:40)
    at GraphQLServiceProject.resolveSchema (C:/Users/Juliu/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_npx/13168/node_modules/apollo/node_modules/apollo-language-server/lib/project/base.js:66:36)
    at Task.task (C:/Users/Juliu/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_npx/13168/node_modules/apollo/lib/commands/service/push.js:70:50)
```

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find a solution since?

Comment: Having a similar solution as well. I'm starting to think it might make more sense to roll our own managed graph service. Apollo Federation Graph Manager has terrible documentation.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple schema files you want to concat them using comma

```
npx apollo service:push --localSchemaFile=$(find src/main/resources/graphql -name "*.graphqls" | tr "\n" "," | sed 's/.$//') --key=$APOLLO_KEY
```

where `src/main/resources/graphql` is path to schema directory